# Having difficulty using threads to count prime numbers in given range

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

```
public void run() {
  System.out.println("Thread running");
  if (threadID == 1) {
    for (int i = 1000000; i < 1250000; i++) {
      if (isPrime(i)) {
        increment();
        a++;
      }
    }
  } else if (threadID == 2) {
    for (int i = 1250000; i < 1500000; i++) {
      if (isPrime(i)) {
        increment();
        b++;
      }
    }
  } else if (threadID == 3) {
    for (int i = 1500000; i < 1750000; i++) {
      if (isPrime(i)) {
        increment();
        c++;
      }
    }
  } else {
    for (int i = 1750000; i <= 2000000; i++) {
      if (isPrime(i)) {
        increment();
        d++;
      }
    }
  }
}

public synchronized void increment() {
  counter++;
}
```

Every time I run the program my counter variable, which is what the synchronized increment method is increasing, prints outs a different answer somewhere in the range of 67,000 to 68,000. I know the answer I should be getting is 70,435 based on another serial implementation I created and WolframAlpha. I'm also certain that my isPrime(int num) method is correct, since when I print the values of the a, b, c, and d ints added together it comes out to 70,435. I believe my issue has something to do with either the synchronization of increment() or how increment() is being used in the run() method, but so far nothing I've tried has worked and I'm at a bit of a loss. Any help or ideas about what could be the issue is greatly appreciated!

Comment: "`if(threadID == 1) {`" this assumes your thread ID is stable (which it might be, but you don't show where this comes from). Why not just create a Runnable which takes two parameters - the start and end - and loop between those.

Comment: "prints outs a different answer" how are you reading `counter` to print it? Is that in a mutually-synchronized block? Please, show a [mcve], it will make it much easier to identify your issue.